# Simulating result by Monte Carlo Simulation

Tags: matlab

I have three variables, lets say a, b and c, i have generated 10,000 random numbers of those variables by normal distribution. Now i want to run monte carlo simulation to get the result in 1000 times.
My model is, Y=0.5*a+0.4*b+0.6*c.
Can anyone please help with matlab code?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

```
v = randn(1000,3);
y = 0.5*v(:,1)+0.4*v(:,2)+0.6*v(:,3);
```

where the columns of `v` are `a,b,c` and `y` is the result.

**Edit:** Given a 10000x3 matrix `v`, compute `y` for 1000 samples randomly selected from `v`.

```
ind = randperm(10000);
y = 0.5*v(ind(1:1000),1) + 0.4*v(ind(1:1000),2) + 0.6*v(ind(1:1000),3);
```

I think the random selection of your random data just complicates things. If `v` is randomly generated, then any set of 1000 samples should be fine.

Comment: @shawpnik In addition to Jacob's answer, you can use `v = normrnd(mu, sigma, [1000 3]);` if you want random variables from a normal distribution with `mu` and `sigma` parameters instead of the unit normal.

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks for your reply. In your code, "v" generates 1000 row and three colum. But i have already generated the "v" matrix for my three different variables with different distribution for each variables. so i have matrix of v, which consists 10000*3 data. Now i want to do the monte carlo simulation, which will take random data from the "v" matrix in 1000 times and will give result of y in 1000 times.